# Java String split not working as expected using a colon (":")

Tags: java, split

I am trying to remove the seconds off of this string:

```
10/31/2009 9:46:16 AM
```

I'm attempting using the following function to do this:

```
public static String correctValue4(String str) {
    String parts[] = str.split(":");
    String fixedStr = parts[0] + ":" + parts[1];
    return fixedStr;
}
```

I figured it would parse through it and get the 10/31/2009 9 and then add the 46 at the end.  However, I am getting a "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1" error upon running.  Obviously, it's not picking up the parts[1].

Any ideas?

For extra karma: I'm needing to append the AM/PM back onto the end of the string.  So, in the end it should look like this:

```
10/31/2009 9:46 AM
```

Thanks, your help is greatly appreciated =)

EDIT:

Sorry, I should have been more specific regarding the date.  What I'm doing is accepting a tab delimited text file into the application and then formatting it and outputting it into  a new file.  All I was needing to do was drop the seconds from the date as per request and output it;  I think I was just way over complicating it.

Tim's answer worked in this case!

Thank you, everyone, who offered suggestions!

Comment: Works for me. What `String` are you passing into your method? (Check it with `System.out`.)

Comment: What you *think* is happening is not happening. Whatever you're passing to that function *isn't* the string you show (which means none of the proposed solutions below are going to help either - your input isn't what you think it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just remove a colon that's followed by two digits if a space is the next character that follows?

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll(":\\d{2}(?= )", "");
```

Comment: While this is better, there's nothing wrong with his existing code per se, he's not passing that string to it (which means none of these proposed solutions are going to help him - his input isn't what he thinks it is).

Answer (score 6):

I would advise a different approach entirely: parse the value into the appropriate domain-specific type (I'd use `LocalDateTime` from [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net)) and then reformat it in the format you want. This will perform validation at the same time, so you don't propagate bad data through your system just because it happens to have a colon in it.

Joda Time provides parse and format facilities (see [`DateTimeFormat`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) and [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)), so it should be pretty simple.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

First parse the Date :

`Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a").format(str);`

Then format the Date :

`new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a").format(d);`

Answer (score 1):

If the String is always of the same format (ending in 2 digits for the seconds, a space and them AM or PM), you can just extract the relevant parts with the `substring` method available on each `String` instance

```
String original = "10/31/2009 9:46:16 AM";
//-6 since we want to remove the : as well
String firstPart = original.substring( 0, original.length() - 6 );
String secondPart = original.substring( original.length() - 3, original.length() );
String result = firstPart + secondPart;
```

Comment: Robin, I actually considered doing it this way, but not all dates accepted from the input file are the same length.  Therefore, it wouldn't have worked =\

Comment: There is still the `lastIndexOf` method which can be used instead of using fixed lengths, but then you might be better of using approaches as suggested by others